# how to get 2 images on top of each other centered inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to fill the width of the browser window.

Inside the div, I want 2 images, on top of each other and each centered within the div. The images might be of any size. Both images need to maintain their aspect ratio and I don't want either of them as background to the div.

```css
  .parent {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .child {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .ontop{
    z-index:1;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
    <img class='child ontop' src="https://i.postimg.cc/yNh7V4v1/spaceship.png">
    <img class='child' src="https://i.postimg.cc/mgB04zzn/universe.jpg">
  </div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleuser123/4twp2dL9/1/)

The problem here is that they are not on top of each other. I can get them on top of each other, and centered, at least horizontally

```css
  .parent {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .child {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
  }
  .ontop{
    z-index:1;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
    <img class='child ontop' src="https://i.postimg.cc/yNh7V4v1/spaceship.png">
    <img class='child' src="https://i.postimg.cc/mgB04zzn/universe.jpg">
  </div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleuser123/tvsm4exh/)

but the problem now is that because of my use of absolute positioning, the images are no longer contained within the div.

Could anyone tell me what the technique would be?

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute;` to place the space ship into the middle center of the parent. This requires the parent to be the same width as the image. I did this in the example using `width: fit-content;`

Using this method you can position the set of images anywhere by putting these three HTML elements into one container which you move around.

```css
.parent {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}

.parent img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="center" src="https://i.postimg.cc/yNh7V4v1/spaceship.png">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/mgB04zzn/universe.jpg">
</div>
```

Want the background image larger, simply change its size? In this example I am going to set it's width to `width: 100vw;` *100 view width*

*(I put as an inline style for this example though you should probably make a CSS rule for your desired size)*

```css
.parent {
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
}

.parent img {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="center" src="https://i.postimg.cc/yNh7V4v1/spaceship.png">
  <img style="width:100vw;" src="https://i.postimg.cc/mgB04zzn/universe.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Liam but this doesn't work. Run your first snippet and make the browser wider. The universe background isn't centered in the div. I need both images centered within the div. Plus, I can't have the background stretched.

Comment: @rgh if you want them centered then place them in a container that is centered.

Comment: @rgh Forgot to mention that you can't just repeat `img` tags. This functionality is only for backgrounds in vanilla CSS/HTML.

Comment: 'place them in a container that is centered'. You mean add 'text-align: center;' to the parent div? That doesn't work. Or introduce some intermediate div?  Could you demonstrate?

Comment: @rgh Here is a fork I made of your fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/YeloPartyHat/z19ewyso/3/ The parent container for the elements has `display:flex;` and `justify-content:center;` to horizontally center the child div on the page.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. However, I want 'each centered within the div'. Here, the spaceship image isn't within the outer div, which becomes apparent if the spaceship image is the larger of the two: [https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleuser123/sxomjzw4/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddleuser123/sxomjzw4/4/)  The images might be of any size. I don't know in advance which, if either, will be the larger.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you move the image(space) to CSS background-image. That is the right approach when you want to the image as a background.

Apply flex to parent and you are good to go.

```css
.parent {
 background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/mgB04zzn/universe.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.child{
      height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
  <img class='child' src="https://i.postimg.cc/yNh7V4v1/spaceship.png">
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dhruvi. Although I used the word 'background' in reply to Liam, I didn't mean to imply that I actually wanted a background-image in the css sense. Perhaps my choice of the stars image was unfortunate as that is what it maybe suggests. The images are also all to maintain their aspect ratio. I've expanded my question slightly to clarify this.